# Sharing TIFFs when asking a question

Tags: discussion, tiff

I am not sure the best way to share an example TIFF for GIS StackExchange. If I write example code in a question, I would like to link to an example TIFF, but not sure the best way to do it. Any ideas about the best approach?

Comment: Unless the question is specific to the values in the raster, I recommend providing the details necessary for potential answerers to easily generate their own dummy data, i.e number of bands, rows and cols, pixel datatype, nodata value, CRS and geotransform. All of this information can be easily generated and copied into your question using `gdalinfo`, `rio info` or the layer properties - information tab in QGIS (or similar in ArcGIS).

Comment: Even better if you could and provide a gdal_create command https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_create.html for creating test data.